# .net - Howto analyze how many different code paths are in a method

Tags: c#, .net, code-coverage, code-analysis

Is there a (preferred free) tool that can analyze how many different combinations are possible in a method? I am currently refactoring a method that has many many if/switch statments and I am curious how many possible different execution ways this method had.

Let's say I have a simple method:

```
public void DoSomething(bool flag1, int value)
{

    if (flag1)
    {
        if (value > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Flag1 & value > 0");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Flag1 & value <= 0");
            return;
        }
    }
    elseif (value > 0 and value < 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Flag1 is false and value between 0 & 10");
        return;
    }

    if (value < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Flag1 = false & value <= 0");
        return;
    }
    elseif(value = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Flag1 = false & value >= 10");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("nothing else matched");

}
```

there should be 6 possible ways in which the this method could be executed.
I know there are tools out there that can calculate this number for me (I believe Visual Studio Ultimate can do this but unfortunately I only own a Professional version).

Maybe someone knows a good tool, that can do this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125898/tool-for-calculating-cyclomatic-complexity?

Comment: Enable code coverage in Visual Studio,its very easy to use. Select project->properties -> code coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CodeMetrics](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CodeMetrics&referringTitle=Home) is a free add-on for the soon no-longer-free Reflector.  No idea how good it is, I got the right version of VS.

Answer (score 3):

What you mean is the [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity), and this calculation is already included with VS 2010, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Are you sure it is included in the Pro Version, how do I use it?

Answer (score 2):

I have been using a tool that can be integrated into VS2008 and VS2010. It can be found from http://www.blunck.info/ccm.html.

Answer (score 1):

The metric you're looking for is "cyclomatic complexity."  There are some free tools but I've used only the VS 2008 pro built-in metrics so I can't judge them, but it should make it easier to find them.

e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Cyclomatic_Complexity.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Code Metrics for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=edd1dfb0-b9fe-4e90-b6a6-5ed6f6f6e615)

You need cyclomatic complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com) (integrated in Visual Studio 2010, 2008, 2005) that can compute the Cyclomatic Complexity on .NET code:

- from source code  definition [here](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#CC)
- from IL code      definition [here](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#ILCC)

The Cyclomatic Complexity on IL code is useful if you decompile an assembly without having the corresponding source code.